# Using Pivot on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

i know that there is a lot of pivots example on stackoverflow and i can understand them, but now i have a problem that i cant solve because is diferent from others problems, please i can accept that you mark this question as duplicate or lower my score, but i need an asnwer, i need to pivot this table

```
 Co_ordenAt                              Co_EnfermedadPatologica                 No_NombreEnfPatologica                     Fl_Diagnostico 
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
83412520141                             1                                       Alergias                                    1              
83412520141                             2                                       Asma                                        1              
83412520141                             3                                       Bronquitis                                  0              
83412520141                             4                                       Diabetes                                    0              
83412520141                             5                                       HTA                                         1  
83412520142                             1                                       Alergias                                    0              
83412520142                             2                                       Asma                                        0              
83412520142                             3                                       Bronquitis                                  0              
83412520142                             4                                       Diabetes                                    1              
83412520142                             5                                       HTA                                         0
```

to be like this table

```
 Co_ordenAt                              Alergia                                Asma                                       Bronquitis                  Diabetes                 HTA
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
83412520141                             Peanuts                                "observasion"                                0                          0                         "observasion"          
83412520142                             0                                       0                                           0                          "observasion"               0
```

I have tried this code

```
SELECT [Co_ordenAt], [Alergia], [Asma] ,[Bronquitis],[Diabetes],[ HTA]
from
(
      SELECT Co_ordenAt,( CASE  WHEN No_Diagnostico='' THEN 'No' ELSE No_Diagnostico END ) as Diagnositco, Co_EnfermedadPatologica, No_NombreEnfPatologica, Fl_Diagnostico, T_AntecedentePersonal.No_Diagnostico
    FROM
    [dbo].[T_AntecedentePersonal] INNER JOIN T_EnfermedadPatologica
    ON T_AntecedentePersonal.Co_EnfermedadPatologica = T_EnfermedadPatologica.Co_EnfedadPatologica
      WHERE Co_ordenAt in (83412520141,83412520142)  
    ) x
pivot
(
  max(Diagnositco)
  FOR No_NombreEnfPatologica in( [Alergia], [Asma] ,[Bronquitis],[Diabetes],[ HTA])
)p
```

where No_Diagnostico is a comment from a doctor if Fl_diagnostico is 1 (means true) or it should say "No" if No_Diagnostico is NULL

But it returns a repeated Co_ordenAt with like the first table but with the columns that i specified, showing null on all of them except the one with Co_enfermedadPatologica (like the first table)

```
83412520141 1   PEANUT  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
83412520141 2   NULL    OBV     NULL    NULL    NULL    
83412520141 3   NULL    NULL    NO      NULL    NULL    
83412520141 4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NO      NULL    
83412520141 5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    OBV 
83412520142 1   NO      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
83412520142 2   NULL    NO      NULL    NULL    NULL    
83412520142 3   NULL    NULL    NO      NULL    NULL    
83412520142 4   NULL    NULL    NULL    OBV     NULL    
83412520142 5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NO
```

i want all in only one row by Co_OrdenAt, but i have tried a lot of codes, even with XML and dynamic queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your inner query you should select only the columns you really need.

Just comment the following columns in your inner query:

- Co_EnfermedadPatologica
- Fl_Diagnostico
- T_AntecedentePersonal.No_Diagnostico

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is correct, you can see a modified version of OP's query in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20cdd/10)

Comment: A more kludgy version would be to group by `Co_ordenAt` and select max on all the enfermedades in the outside query.